# Why is the page loads two times by pingdom tools?

Tags: performance, load, double, pingdom

The problem is that the page loads 2 times, reported by pingdom.

The page is [www.klikmk.com](http://www.klikmk.com)

The speed looks fine most of the time, but could be better if there is no double load. I am looking in the code also as html with firebug, but I can't find it where it is called 2 times.

[Picture](http://tinypic.com/r/33usiyq/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load of a page 2 times can also occur when you have an image with missing or empty src tag